How to save data from qdrant to azure blob storage/file share storage?
I have a qdrant that is deployed in a docker container in the azure app service. Data from qdrant collections is saved in the docker container itself - this is the main problem, because when the application is restarted, all the data that was in the container disappears. I need to save data in a separate storage, preferably a blob/file share. I'm not considering the possibility of deploying qdrant in Kubernetes and container instance
I tried to specify the path to save the data in the azure application configurations, different paths where azure saves the data, but nothing came of it. I also tried to do this using the qdrant docker configuration, but nothing came of it either.

To save data from Qdrant to Azure Blob Storage or File Share Storage, follow these steps:

If you are using Azure Container Service, start by creating a storage account and then create a file share within that storage account.
Use the following command to save the STORAGE_KEY:

STORAGE_KEY=$(az storage account keys list --resource-group <resource_group_name> --account-name <storage_account_name>  --query "[0].value" --output tsv)


Next, run the following command to create the Qdrant container, which will expose port 6333 and write to the Azure file share:

az container create --resource-group <resource_group_name> \
    --name qdrant --image qdrant/qdrant --dns-name-label qdrant \
    --ports 6333 --azure-file-volume-account-name <storage_account_name> \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key $STORAGE_KEY \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name <file_share_name> \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /qdrant/storage

This will save data from Qdrant to Azure File Share Storage.

What are the logs saying in regard to your issue? You might want to increase the log level in your config.yml.
This is how I would approach this (disclaimer: not tested):
#  mount an Azure Files share to your Docker container
docker run -d \
    --name qdrant-container \
    -v <azure_files_mount_point>:/mnt/qdrant-data \
    -e AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT="<storage_account_name>" \
    -e AZURE_STORAGE_KEY="<storage_account_key>" \
    your-qdrant-image

config.yaml:
# increase debug level
log_level: DEBUG

# specify the path on the mounted volume where you want to store Qdrant data
storage:
  storage_path: /mnt/qdrant-data

